# NullPointerValue error in Java game

Tags: java

So here is the deal, I have been working on a coding project and I have a tester and a class-well 2 of each actually-and on my second class I keep receiving a null pointer value error. I believe it to be coming from my Pond constructor.

The class with actual problems is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 * This class represents a grid of lily pads in a pond 
 * for the purpose of playing Frogs and Toads. 
 *  
 * do not begin working on this until the Pad class is fully tested and debugged
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class Pond
{

    private Pad [][] grid; // the 2D array of Pad objects that make up our pond
    int size;              // the number of Pads in a row or column

    /**
     *     Creates a grid of lily pads with height and width both equal 
     *     to the given size; each lily pad is constructed with the appropriate 
     *     status (frog, toad, or a vacant spot) for starting a game of 
     *     Frogs and Toads. 
     *     
     *     The starting configuration consists of a vacant 
     *     lily pad in the center and the remaining lily pads being half 
     *     occupied by frogs and half occupied by toads. Each (vertical) 
     *     column with a higher index than the middle column starts with 
     *     all toads, and each column with an index lower than the middle 
     *     column starts with all frogs. The center column has frogs in 
     *     the high row indices, toads in the low row indices, and a vacant 
     *     spot in the middle.
     *     
     *     Internally, an instance of this class contains "size * size" 
     *     instances of the Pad class (stored in a 2D array). The legal 
     *     range of size is odd numbers from 3 up to 9, which is assumed 
     *     by the constructor as a precondition.
     *     
     *     @param size - the height and width of the grid (assumed to be 
     *     an odd number at least 3 and at most 9 as a precondition)
     */
    public Pond(int size)
    {   
        // check that size is an odd number between 3 and 9
        //  HINT   size%2  computes the remainder of size/2.  
        //         if (size%2 == 1) that means size is odd
        //         so there are three conditions on size: must be >=3, <=9 AND odd

    grid = new Pad[size][size];
    Pad a = new Pad(Pad.Frog);
    Pad b = new Pad(Pad.Toad);
    Pad c = new Pad(Pad.Vacant);
    int d = (size-1)/2;
    grid[d][d] = c;
    int e,rows1;
    int f=size-1;
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<d; j++){
                    grid[i][j]=a;

        }
        for(int j=f; j>d; j--){
        grid[i][j]=b;
        }  
   }
            // now fill each cell with a new Pad(Pad.XXXX) 
        //        XXX will be FROG, TOAD, or VACANT 
   if (size%2 == 1 && size>=3 && size<=9){
        this.size=size;
        }
        else {
        System.out.println("Error size is not an odd number between 3 and 9");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    //         if this is NOT true, print an error message and return. Otherwise...
         // declare the 2D array of Pad
}
    /**
     * Indicates whether or not all lily pads in the pond are in the solved state. 
     * 
     * @return true if the puzzle is solved and false otherwise.
     */
    public boolean isSolved()
    { // use the following algorithm:
        //  create an int variable to count numSolved and set it to 0
        int numSolved = 0;
        //   use a nested for loop to visit each cell in grid.  
        //       If the cell at row, col is solved, then add one to numSolved
        for (int i=0 ; i>size ; i++){
            if (isSolved()==true){
                numSolved = numSolved+1;
            }
        }
        if (numSolved == size*size){
            return true;
        }
        else{return false;}
        //  after the loop, if numSolved == size*size  then it's solved (return true) 
        //   otherwise it's not (false)


    }

    /**
     *  Returns a reference to the Pad object at the specified row and column of the pond. 
     *  (note: rows and columns are counted starting from 0). 
     */

    public Pad getPad(int row, int col) {
        // if row & col are between 0 and size-1,
        if(-1>row && row<0 && -1>col && col<0){
            return grid[row][col];
        }
        else {
            Pad x = new Pad(Pad.Invalid);
            return x;
        //  return grid[row][col]
        // else return a reference to an INVALID Pad
    }
    }

    /**
     *  Returns the width of the pond (which is the same as its height). 
     */
    public int getSize(){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please input size of grid");
        size = keyboard.nextInt();
        return size;
    }


    /**
     *  Resets the pond to the state it was in when originally created. 
     */
    public void reset(){
        for (int i=0; i>size; i++){
            for (int j=0; j>size; j++) {
                Pad x = new Pad(Pad.Frog);
                grid [i][j]=x;
                reset();
        }
    }
}


    /**
     * Returns the current state of the pond as a String (with the VACANT, FROG, 
     * TOAD, and VACANT Pads represented as defined by the toString() method of 
     * the Pad class).
     */
    public String toString(){
        String result="";
        for (int row=0; row<size; row++){
            for (int col=0; col<size; col++){
                result = result + grid[row][col].toString(); // add the next grid Pad in a row
            }
            result = result + "\n";  // go to a new line after each row
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

My tester class that is not showing error when run is:

```
  /**
     * Write a description of class PondTester2 here.
     * 
     * @author (your name) 
     * @version (a version number or a date)
     */
    public class PondTester {

        public static void main(String [] args){

            Pond pool = new Pond(3); // smallest size pool
            assert(pool.toString().equals("FTT\nF T\nFFT\n")): "Pond toString failed.";
            assert (pool.isSolved()==false): "Fail. Pond isSolved() should be false";

            // 1) before starting you must fully complete and debug the Pad class first using PadTester
            // 2) Then in Pond class define the isSolved, getPad, getSize and reset methods, then test here
            // 3) activate the following test code and verify

            // TEST CASE 
            assert pool.getSize()==3 : "Fail. Pond getSize() should return 3. Actual value returned "+pool.getSize() ;
            assert pool.getPad(0,0).getStatus() == Pad.Frog : "Pond getPad(0,0) should return FROG";
            assert pool.getPad(2,2).getStatus() == Pad.Toad : "Pond getPad(2,2) should return TOAD";
            assert pool.getPad(1,1).getStatus() == Pad.Vacant : "Pond getPad(1,1) should return VACANT";

            // Let's solve the 3x3 case

            pool.getPad(0,0).setStatus(Pad.Toad);
            pool.getPad(1,0).setStatus(Pad.Toad);
            pool.getPad(2,0).setStatus(Pad.Toad);        
            pool.getPad(0,1).setStatus(Pad.Frog);
            pool.getPad(2,1).setStatus(Pad.Toad);        
            pool.getPad(0,2).setStatus(Pad.Frog);        
            pool.getPad(1,2).setStatus(Pad.Frog);        
            pool.getPad(2,2).setStatus(Pad.Frog);   
            assert(pool.toString().equals("TFF\nT F\nTTF\n")): "Pond toString failed.";
            assert pool.isSolved()==true : "Fail.  Pond isSolved() should be true."; 

            pool.reset();   // back to start state

            assert(pool.toString().equals("FTT\nF T\nFFT\n")): "Pond toString failed.";
            assert pool.isSolved()==false : "Fail.  Pond reset() did not reset pond.";

            System.out.println("PondTester2 done. All tests passed.");
        }
    }
```

Pad is an object I made in another class I am just curious what is wrong with my constructor because it is not adding values, or so I am assuming.

Comment: You don't have to guess where it's coming from. The stacktrace of the exception will clearly tell you the line number. Please put that.

Comment: Post the stack trace